# Web-based open-source board games and board game engines

Tags: open-source, web-apps, web-server, game

I recently set up a virtual **board game** platform for private use and I am still looking for open-source implementations of board games (it might also be similar one-shot games).

I already found https://github.com/jbowens/codenames which would eventually work from the docker container.

Are there more open-source games, engines or favorably docker images you can recommend?

Answer (score 1):

If your are looking for open source games. I think you should definitely checkout the Python Games repository.

https://github.com/asweigart/PythonStdioGames

This below repository has a good collection.
Although it is not Open Source since it has Apache License.

https://github.com/grantjenks/free-python-games